# Injection of HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, jboss7.x

I am using ejb 3 and trying to @Inject HttpServletRequest, but while deploying I occur exception.

Code:

```
@Inject private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
```

Exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [HttpServletRequest] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private com.kmware.ttk.highway.beans.session.UserSessionBean.httpRequest]
```

What could I do with that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The lifecycle of HttpServletRequest is managed by the EJB/web container, not the CDI container. Attempting to inject it leads to issues because there are typically many implementations of the interface,and your CDI container does not have enough information to make a decision on which implementation to inject. Even if you successfully injected an instance of it, it would ***not*** be the same instance as being managed by the EJB container.

To acquire a properly managed instance of the request, do this instead:

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
```

Comment: Did you mean @javax.ws.rs.core.Context ?

Comment: @KirillBazarov - yes, thats the annotations to use.

Comment: @KirillBazarov - did this solve your problem? If so feel free to upvote/accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Noted should be that `@Context` works only inside a JAX-RS webservice class, and definitely don't work inside an EJB class. Perhaps the OP is coincidentally actually using JAX-RS as well even though that was *nowhere* mentioned in the question. Therefore, this answer looks at first glance a completely blind guess and an ignorant shoot in the dark, and after all a lucky shot.

Comment: Nah, when you've been working a web service implementation for a year you kind of recognize when someone else is running into the same problems as you did early in the process.

Comment: Hi I did your resolution, but it thrown me the exception below: Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnserializableDependencyException: WELD-001413: The bean Managed Bean [class com.ReviewController] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named] declares a passivating scope but has a non-passivation-capable dependency com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension$ParameterBean@1520cac
Regards

Answer (score 10):

If your dependent is a JAX-RS (Restful) class then note the answer above. On the other hand, if you've got a more complex arrangement of dependency injection the question is certainly valid.

This capability has been added to the CDI 1.1 specification (JSR-346) which in turn has been added to the new Java EE 7 specification. In other words, the newest class of Java Enterprise Application servers will be able to handle this.

In the meantime, if you need to be able to manage some request scopes dependencies that in term need access to the actual HttpServletRequest information, you can use your approach and use the [JBoss Solder](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/Solder) tool. (Don't panic if the web site looks defunct, the fact of the matter is the work got shifted to the official CDI 1.1 spec implementation—i.e. "Weld 2"—so they aren't working on solder any more. But it's still perfectly suitable for CDI 1.0.)

The maven dependencies would be

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.solder</groupId>
  <artifactId>solder-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.solder</groupId>
  <artifactId>solder-impl</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```