# CDI and HttpRequest

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest, cdi

I am using a helper class in a servlet to remove some code from the servlet itself. I am injecting this helper class in the servlet with the CDI @Inject and this is also marked as @RequestScoped bean. Since this helper class is used to remove some code from the servlet I need access to the httprequest, response and session in this class. Is there a way to make these available via injection? I tried to use @inject on a field of type
HttpServletRequest but I get an error from WELD.

Comment: The best way would be to switch to Java EE 7. If you can't do that, take a look at these alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189337/inject-httpservletrequest-in-cdi-sessionscoped-bean and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419887/injection-of-httpservletrequest

Comment: @helderdarocha I am using Glassfish 4.0...so I should be using Java EE 7.

Comment: If the helper class is stateless consider marking it @ApplicationScoped.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of alternative solutions to this.

1. You could pass the `HttpServletRequest` to the helper. I mean instead of the helper being:

   ```
   @Inject HttpServletRequest request;

   public Xxx doSomeHelperWork() {
       // use request
   }
   ```

   Make it:

   ```
   public Xxx doSomeHelperWork(HttpServletRequest request) {
       // use request
   }
   ```
2. Use the [DeltaSpike servlet module](http://deltaspike.apache.org/servlet.html) which can handle the injection of `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was already using Google Guice for this however I would like to switch to CDI and Java EE. It seems something so simple that it must be possible with CDI