# Getting HttpServletRequest using CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

Is this right way to get HttpServletRequest using CDI in a non Bean

`HttpServletRequest request = CDI.current().select(HttpServletRequest.class).get();`

Edit :

I want to access the HttpServletRequest for logging session session information like username etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13420108/140925

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Injection of HttpServletRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419887/injection-of-httpservletrequest)

Comment: I want to access the HttpServletRequest in logger class for printing session information to logs.

Answer (score 2):

To acquire a properly managed instance of the request, do this instead:

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
```

Source: [Injection of HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419887/injection-of-httpservletrequest)